# Pyramid Scheme Negation

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

In my language [Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Pyramid-Scheme), there is a slightly funny construct: the empty triangle:

```
^
-
```

When given no arguments, it returns `0`. To generate `1` using this construct, we could use this:

```
   ^
  /!\
 ^---
 -
```

This simply passes `0` to the negation function. We can continue negating this result:

```
 ^
/!\
---^
  /!\
 ^---
 -
```

To get 0. One more negation gives:

```
   ^
  /!\
 ^---
/!\
---^
  /!\
 ^---
 -
```

### Challenge

Given an integer **n** ≥ 1, output the empty pyramid being negated **n** times in the described fashion.

### Test cases

```
input
output

1
   ^
  /!\
 ^---
 -

2
 ^
/!\
---^
  /!\
 ^---
 -

3
   ^
  /!\
 ^---
/!\
---^
  /!\
 ^---
 -

6
 ^
/!\
---^
  /!\
 ^---
/!\
---^
  /!\
 ^---
/!\
---^
  /!\
 ^---
 -
```

Comment: By negation here I suppose you means bitwise complement (`~`)?

Comment: @user202729 No, I mean regular negation.

Comment: So it's C/C++ `!` (`not`).

Comment: @user202729 Yes. Though what it means is tangential to the problem

Comment: I had to stare at the examples in the Pyramid Scheme README for a solid 10 minutes before I figured out how it works. Cool stuff. 

Comment: /!\ Warning! /!\ I see warning triangles everywhere!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 17 bytes

```
ＦＮ«↙^→/!\¶³‖Ｔ»↓^-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NToZqLM6AoM69Ew8olvzzPJzWtREdBKU5J0xouHpSZngES1FeMiYnJQ5IxBjGDUtNyUpNLQooS84qB5udqAAVruZCMBBmnC9T1/7/xf92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＮ«
```

Loop for the appropriate number of negations.

```
↙^→/!\¶³
```

Print a negation function. (The `³` expands to `---`.)

```
‖Ｔ
```

Reflect the canvas.

```
»↓^-
```

At the end of the loop, print the empty triangle.

Comment: Just fyi, the empty triangle uses `-` instead of `_`

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Thanks for pointing that out! I did think it didn't quite look right, but couldn't place my finger on it...

Answer (score 14):

## [Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Pyramid-Scheme), 
<s>31655 bytes, non-competing (obviously...)</s>  
<s>16989</s> <s>12901</s> 8465 bytes, somewhat-competing

So, I thought this would be a funny thing to try.

### Edits:

- -14666 bytes by finally getting around to [adding some compiler optimisation to psll](https://github.com/MarcinKonowalczyk/psll-lang/commit/597f0de1b9718532319360259fa68fd07ce9d610)
- -4088 bytes by using different optimisation technique
- -4436 bytes by [implementing automatic variable name shortening into psll](https://github.com/MarcinKonowalczyk/psll-lang/commit/67c02355f27cbc3cdd238d4b20475cb6320190eb) (I really wanted the Explanation psll code to compile into the answer *without* any modifications)

```
      ^    ^  ^          ^             ^  ^        ^          ^        ^      ^  ^          ^          ^                ^       ^                 ^          ^
     ^-   / \ -^        / \           ^- / \       -^        / \      ^-     / \ -^        / \        / \              ^-      / \               / \        / \
    ^-   /set\ -^      /set\         ^- /set\       -^      /set\    ^-     /set\ -^      /set\      /set\            / \     /set\             /   \      /out\
   ^-   ^-----^ -^    ^-----^       ^- ^-----^       -^    ^-----^   -^    ^-----^ -^    ^-----^    ^-----^          ^---^   ^-----^           /     \    ^-----^
  ^-   /f\   / \ -^  /t\   /f\     ^- /r\   /+\       -^  /r\   /+\   -^  /r\   /+\ -^  /r\   /+\  /r\   /+\        ^-  / \ /l\   /0\         / loop  \  /s\   /d\
  -^   ---  /chr\ -^ ---   ---    ^-  ---  ^---^       -^ ---  ^---^   -^ ---  ^---^ -^ ---  ^---^ ---  ^---^      ^-  /   \---   ---        ^---------^ ---   ---
   -^      ^----- / \            / \      /r\ /e\       -^    /r\ /f\   -^    /r\ /c\ -^    /r\ /d\    /r\ /e\    ^-  /     \               /!\       / \
    -^    / \    ^---^          ^---^     --- ---       / \   --- ---    -^   --- --- / \   --- ---    --- ---   ^-  /       \             ^---      /   \
     -^  /47 \  / \  -^        / \  -^                 /   \              -^         /   \                      ^-  /         \           /!\       /     \
      -^ ----- /set\  -^      /set\  -^               /     \              -^       /     \                    ^-  /           \         ^---      /       \
       -^     ^-----^  -^    ^-----^  -^             /       \              -^     /       \                  ^-  /      ?      \       / \       ^---------^
        -^   /a\   / \  -^  /t\   /+\  -^           /         \              -^   /         \                ^-  ^---------------^     /<=>\     / \       / \
         -^  ---  /chr\  -^ ---  ^---^  -^         ^-----------^             ^-  ^-----------^              ^-  /!\             / \   ^-----^   /   \     /set\
         / \     ^-----  / \    /t\ /a\  -^       / \         / \           ^-  / \         / \            ^-  ^---            /   \ /l\   /n\ /     \   ^-----^
        /   \   / \     /   \   --- ---   -^     /set\       /set\         ^-  /set\       /set\          ^-  /?\             /     \---   ---/       \ /l\   /+\
       /     \ /33 \   /     \             -^   ^-----^     ^-----^       ^-  ^-----^     ^-----^        ^-  ^---^           /       \       /         \---  ^---^
      /       \-----  /       \             -^ /r\   /+\   /r\   /+\     ^-  /r\   /+\   /r\   /+\      ^-  /m\ / \         ^---------^     /           \   /l\ /1\
     /         \     ^---------^            / \---  ^---^  ---  ^---^   ^-   ---  ^---^  ---  ^---^    ^-   ---/   \       / \       / \   /             \  --- ---
    ^-----------^   / \       / \          /   \   /r\ /s\     /r\ /s\ ^-        /r\ /d\     /r\ /d\  ^-      /     \     /out\     /out\ /               \
   / \         ^-  /set\     /set\        /     \  --- ---     --- ---/ \        --- ---     --- --- ^-      /       \   ^-----^   ^-----/                 \
  /set\       ^-  ^-----^   ^-----^      ^-------^                   /   \                          ^-      ^---------^ /s\   /c\ /e\   /                   \
 ^-----^     ^-  /b\   / \ /d\   / \    ^-      ^-                  /     \                        ^-      / \       / \---   --- ---  /                     \
/n\   /#\   ^-   ---  /chr\---  /chr\  ^-      ^-                  /       \                      / \     /out\     /out\             /                       \
---  ^---  ^-        ^-----    ^----- ^-      / \                 /         \                    /   \   ^-----^   ^-----            /                         \
    /l\   / \       / \       / \    ^-      /   \               ^-----------^                  /     \ /s\   /s\ /s\               /                           \
   /ine\ /   \     /92 \     /45 \  ^-      /     \              -^         / \                /       \---   --- ---              /                             \
   -----/     \    -----     ----- ^-      /       \              -^       /set\              /         \                         /                               \
       /       \                  ^-      /         \              -^     ^-----^            ^-----------^                       /                                 \
      /         \                ^-      ^-----------^              -^   /r\   /+\          / \         / \                     /                                   \
     ^-----------^              ^-       -^         / \              -^  ---  ^---^        /set\       /   \                   ^-------------------------------------^
    / \         ^-             / \        -^       /set\              -^     /r\ /s\      ^-----^     /     \                 / \                                   / \
   /set\       ^-             /   \        -^     ^-----^             / \    --- ---     /m\   /n\   / loop  \               /   \                                 /   \
  ^-----^     ^-             /     \        -^   /r\   /c\           ^---^               ---   ---  ^---------^             /     \                               /     \
 /s\   / \   ^-             /       \        -^  ---   ---          / \  -^                        / \       / \           /       \                             /   ?   \
 ---  /chr\ ^-             /         \        -^                   /set\  -^                      /   \     /set\         /         \                           ^---------^
     ^-----/ \            ^-----------^        -^                 ^-----^  -^                    / <=> \   ^-----^       ^-----------^                         /!\       ^-
    / \   /   \           -^         / \        -^               /r\   /+\  -^                  ^-------^ /m\   /-\     / \         / \                       ^---      / \
   /32 \ /     \           -^       /set\        -^              ---  ^---^  -^                / \     / \---  ^---^   /set\       /   \                     / \       /out\
   -----/       \           -^     ^-----^       / \                 /r\ /a\  -^              /<=>\   /-1 \   /m\ /2\ ^-----^     /     \                   /   \     ^-----
       ^---------^           -^   /t\   /+\     /   \                --- ---  / \            ^-----^  -----   --- ---/k\   /l\   / loop  \                 /  ?  \   /t\
      / \       / \           -^  ---  ^---^   /     \                       /   \          /m\   /2\                ---   ---  ^---------^               ^-------^  ---
     /set\     /set\           -^     /t\ /d\ /       \                     /     \         ---   ---                          / \       / \             /!\     ^-
    ^-----^   ^-----^          / \    --- ---/         \                   /       \                                          /   \     /set\           ^---    / \
   /e\   / \ /c\   / \        /   \         ^-----------^                 /         \                                        / <=> \   ^-----^         / \     /out\
   ---  /chr\---  /chr\      /     \       / \         / \               ^-----------^                                      ^-------^ /k\   /-\       /<=>\   ^-----
       ^-----    ^-----     /       \     /set\       /set\             / \         / \                                    / \     / \---  ^---^     ^-----^ /r\
      / \       / \        /         \   ^-----^     ^-----^           /set\       /set\                                  /<=>\   /-1 \   /k\ /2\   /+\   /1\---
     /10 \     /94 \      ^-----------^ /t\   /+\   /t\   /+\         ^-----^     ^-----^                                ^-----^  -----   --- ---  ^---^  ---
     -----     -----     / \         / \---  ^---^  ---  ^---^       /r\   /+\   /r\   /+\                              /k\   /2\                 /k\ /m\
                        /set\       /set\   /t\ /d\     /t\ /d\      ---  ^---^  ---  ^---^                             ---   ---                 --- ---
                       ^-----^     ^-----^  --- ---     --- ---          /r\ /b\     /r\ /e\
                      /t\   /+\   /t\   /+\                              --- ---     --- ---
                      ---  ^---^  ---  ^---^
                          /t\ /b\     /t\ /e\
                          --- ---     --- ---
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVnbbhwpEH3vryDKo4XI2F5FkZL1jyCkZDxRIsdxNDP7kK/3dnM9VVTReB7a0EXDoS6nCvzn7/nr889Hezn@OD2fXl9N/IX8CKb@oMlk0qDQDxvMBi86AflqSX/s@nDGG1tlWw/GWXghDIoTDKags7UPegH7amnwLqdrmz31EB686AYVeNoUdDYA0QlWiSkA3ct/1wgwTh/s9gt5@tKr@OgLPoj2uynox/lFkAQRX0aYhUtR4HcPJnJxX@ldUuA5vrhBJeI72mdS/nFccVvK/YqCDx4A/np5@RMhuksUPm5KTGqw22fHH@e4QOzlZ5wwNgNVI3lH@6zHPk4IVxxkmaY3277angv4VRrAfbd2N2W4E3XG@O67p/2jx96jZx8XhKaPkXeehUiepxlecJa0ybbRNBreVRu03aG0NhswDi3U2aNql@ZJ9x@jxbcHYwjbM5Tr9wyjBCl1OyNgQ5WZhi07ia0EwtihAycapI6SzSVAw0FUaQiuTFzDnNEBQyfbpIxSpAzbAx3UfByiYiEzu68eTZmJ5YYrTzZLnUSTJnBtcQuM5z5/@dczmK4pL00NnML5AvCFbnJt@SCo7p0XUljj5uaw0auWjjIyoZT@psKoVfArb9TMPJBW9H10ZWb@7cFpA7NvAV7TYe43KiiWgDzZpeaBNIkfvBRilXqb42bMN1WFBbq7u8tAexfqEmWXmwfSKg6DOAPnbe61sLHVxEbGiCmUptOoI1WaxM@eWD7wSGHEsynSHbIaeewF2dcd7o4l41BTqCStYicyiwPTAZLsZIsUnk6YBv11S6IX37Lx2g41BiDbtnawPYPHAg9ajjFT1B9VOzo4cXXHtoX5GKYQpAyaYeSSWq7j9A0cIqB@Trw8yNS2l2yxjkefyWXdsRQyTvhuRUeDbh32rVBNMk4tZuhKu8l4dMhwWO6ReOTwNmJcpe898e6YRzCj7KNT8TnFy4yYNDm@GmC4dskjtaUfs4YpFw3PfWYGXqlgMl@rMU9c23fWU5Muof7kbZcW8TP4SvD@/H3ymJ8/3ZbW/T9GoQW5JvWq@ZnHzQLMECG8vSl901oSO4ilaXeU3fOACYRQqu6Ul/sloHSa3XOCKYgN5E6VubNgyjz8pDssv96AsaLcKTZ3Pa9Pv12FplicV9nyL1U2PO3JNzgj7yulCeRq4gEaubtRPjLs7ohnQC2z6R5Y1sP43cqtVDuT@4y3JE5Dj8k8GepJDr3w6I10zAcdW1KYWXF7ZgJpPTRnujVeA8qgdrcr@qlfSxJz6RRGPSSokKcVpEbwVDJOuQToTEzde4ZXhQN1qeT8LgEKgLQ7gQppPSuzfD7Lr3jADXahJbvfzYf9FcpZviEwvBrNYWb9NM3Sy5TEAHdbSu@9XKamjvPl6wJewtGj0RTZEkcvN8mklvd7GVKs6s787qAI8mWJs4dkvO3IeOunKBd3kcYvykETOeqKmVJUA1ThXnZmS4on9@ShqpR5Ny71kM@B15b5ZVLpkuWYDtkusoPeihvb4V1y7KoaVU6PkC6v6Xw0ZkO@C4GFZ2m3RX/As7j43weaKsc0OEfnU3zbor7E/KkeJY@e/0/JiPckVrmGfiNIjWfZcW9RD5S99ca8N0fgGsE@IcE2jpBinLaY@QY3fNPMPcWsTa8r0Y1im9pucMG3i17Gx9n0yWceyHd0B99i@vChHi/vjZfshlxJedPsoh/YuGdQvKBbjHSeFAymX@yZ4c2kqrwnhTaTGp/hhlwuyEi7MKJhbTOELf90nsTbyJG@me67yzyaqL95/I@hMvnYOdR9sJWXwY47JS0D410B93WEWwHy@no4/A8)

### Explanation

```cs
(set n (# line)) // Set n to line input

(set space (chr 32))
(set newline (chr 10))
(set caret (chr 94))
(set fslash (chr 47))
(set bang (chr 33))
(set bslash (chr 92))
(set dash (chr 45))

// Left triangle
(set lt fslash)
(set lt (+ lt bang)) (set lt (+ lt bslash)) (set lt (+ lt newline))
(set lt (+ lt dash)) (set lt (+ lt dash)) (set lt (+ lt dash))

// Right triangle
(set rt caret) (set rt (+ rt newline))
(set rt (+ rt space)) (set rt (+ rt space))
(set rt (+ rt fslash)) (set rt (+ rt bang)) (set rt (+ rt bslash))
(set rt (+ rt newline))
(set rt (+ rt space)) (set rt (+ rt caret))
(set rt (+ rt dash)) (set rt (+ rt dash)) (set rt (+ rt dash))
(set rt (+ rt newline))

// n = mod(m,2)
((set m n) (loop (<=> (<=> m 2) -1) (set m (- m 2))))

// Print the top and the first triangle
(? (! (? m ( // If m
    (out space space) (out space)
))) ( // Else
    (out space caret) (out newline)
))

(set l 0)
(loop (! (! (<=> l n))) ( // While l < n
    ((set k l) (loop (<=> (<=> k 2) -1) (set k (- k 2)))) // k = mod(l,2)
    (? (! (? (! (<=> (+ k m) 1)) ( // If xor(k,m)
        (out rt)
    ))) ( // Else
        (out lt)
    ))
(set l (+ l 1))
))
(out space dash) // Final triangle
```

Comment: I applaud your determination. This may not be the shortest answer, but it seems like you worked really hard on this. +1

Comment: Why is this non-competing?

Comment: @pppery, Is this better?  The answer was non-competing because I didn't feel like it was actually code golf. I wrote it because I wanted to write a [meta-language for Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/MarcinKonowalczyk/psll-lang) (and because I thought the idea of answering a question about Pyramid Scheme *in* Pyramid Scheme was hilarious). I've now actually gotten to the point to where I've implemented some (rudimentary) compiler optimisations and therefore can generate much smaller code. It's not done by any stretch of the imagination though. Hence only _'somewhat-competing'_.

Comment: Yes. The reason I was asking is that the term "non-competing" is often used to mean "Uses a language released after the challenge" (which [no longer requires any annotation](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12877/46076)), "doesn't meat the spec in some way", or "not a [serious contender](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8750/46076)" (both of which [should be handled by deleting the answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7990/46076)). Since I don't know the language well enough to know what the situation is, I asked.

Comment: non-competing does not mean "not really golfed". Such answers are usually called "baseline" not "non-competing". "non-competing" indicates your answer have to break one of the rules for some reason.

Comment: @pppery and HighlyRadioactive, Thank you very much for clarifying. I think the only one this answer **used to** fall under was the "serious contender" clause. As far as I'm concerned, however, I have actually (and will continue to) put a lot of effort into making the code shorter.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 94 bytes

```python
i=input();print i%2*2*" "+" ^"
while i:print['/!\\\n---^','  /!\\\n ^---'][i%2];i-=1
print" -"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBCoAgEEX3nmIaCMsaItsVnURzFzQQJmFEp7ew5X/v/fDE7fA6JZ7ZhytW9RRO9hG41EorBGwQHIp7430FHrM0siustZ6InGwlwD/BfUAu5rsuE9Pci1wjEKY0vA)

Trying to golf this... 3 `print` statements seem awfully redundant.

Answer (score 3):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 101 bytes

```
a=>{k=" ^---"for i:0..a print(["   ^",k,"---^"][i?~i%2+1:i]+"\n"+" "*(~i%2)*2+"/!\\")print(k+"\n -")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYvdCoMgGIZv5dsLgWa2LdhJYF1IJnQifAga4tnYbt2KTp@fPaeSYvWmbmb6BgNyWmv4lInHV99vtGeORSwgIocudDi9w7rw/OdmUO@RVwUboUBoxcVkOyg8H9ZC3nO4AtKQv@rFR9YD)

also too long lol

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 5, 77+1 (-p) bytes

```
$\=' ^
 _';map$_%2?$\=~s,\^,  ^
  /!\\
 ^---,:$\=~s,  \^,^
/!\\
---^,,1..$_}{
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxlZdIY5LIV7dOjexQCVe1cgeKFRXrBMTp6MAklDQV4yJ4VKI09XV1bGCSCkoACXjuMASQOE4HR1DPT2V@Nrq//8NDf7lF5Rk5ucV/9ctAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 95 bytes

```
n=>{print((n%2)?" ^":"   ^")fori=n i>0i--print({"  /!\\\n ^---","/!\\\n---^"}[i%2])print"   -"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678n2b7P8/WrrqgKDOvREMjT9VI015JIU7JSklBAUhppuUXZdrmKWTaGWTq6kIUVQOl9BVjYmLyFOJ0dXWVdJQgPCA7Tqk2OlPVKFYTrBJkhK5S7f80DUNjzf8A)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>77</s> 74 bytes

```
n=>(s=`^
  /!\\
 ^---`,n%2?`   `+s:` ^`)+`
/!\\
---${s}`.repeat(n/2)+`
 -`
```

#### Try it:

```js
f=

n=>(s=`^
  /!\\
 ^---`,n%2?`   `+s:` ^`)+`
/!\\
---${s}`.repeat(n/2)+`
 -`
```

```html
<input oninput=o.innerHTML=f(value)>
<pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>70</s> <s>68</s> 60 bytes

*thanks to @MartinEnder for -8 bytes*

```
.+
$*
r`11
21
1
¶  /!\¶ ^---
2
¶/!\¶---^
^¶( *)
$1 ^$&
$
¶ -
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYurKMHQkMvIkMuQ69A2BQV9xRggFaerq8tlBBQAc4GcOK64Q9s0FLQ0uVQMFeJU1LhUQKp1//83AwA)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 104 bytes

```java
n->{String r=n%2>0?"   ^\n":" ^\n";for(;n-->0;r+=n%2<1?"  /!\\\n ^---\n":"/!\\\n---^\n");return r+" -";}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##nVBNi8IwEL3vr5gNCAmS@rGwh43WX6CXPW4VsjFKtE5Lmgoi/e110vaoFyFDePPeY@bNSV@1LEqLp/25NbmuKlhrh/cPAIfB@oM2FjYRAvwG7/AIhhMDKBQ1Gyp6VdDBGdgAwhJalOl90PoljubpdMXIvsuQ/bDuU4fCc4VSplPlx1GzmEXN5DPLMoSdlLIT95hQNAnlbag9gh8zkEw1reqnl/V/TtOHJa6F28OFMvB@h78taDEEuFXBXpKiDklJVMiRY2L4THRZnvKvmeicv@38etv5LYbLN@0D)

```java
n->{                       // Method with integer parameter and String return-type
  String r=                //  Result-String, starting at:
           n%2>0?          //  If the input is odd:
            "   ^\n"       //   Start the result at "   ^" + new-line
           :               //  Else (the input is even):
            " ^\n";        //   Start the result at " ^" + new-line
  for(;n-->0;              //  Loop the input amount of times
    r+=n%2<1?              //   If the current row is even:
        "  /!\\\n ^---\n"  //    Append the result-String with "  /!\" + new-line
                           //                                  " ^---" + new-line
       :                   //   Else (the current row is odd):
        "/!\\\n---^\n"     //    Append the result-String with "/!\" + new-line
                           //                                  "---^" + new-line
  );                       //  End of loop
  return r                 //  Return the result-String
          +" -";           //   + " -"
}                          // End of method
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 73 bytes

```python
lambda n:n%2*'  '+' ^%s\n -'%(-~n/2*r"""
/!\
---^
  /!\
 ^---""")[n%2*9:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk/VSEtdQUFdW10hTrU4Jk9BV11VQ7cuT99Iq0hJSYlLXzGGS1dXN45LQQHEVIgDcoDimtEgjZZWsf8LijLzShTSNCw1/wMA)

Golfing [TFeld's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148486/20260).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 167 bytes

```python
def f(n):
	g=[[" "]*5for _ in'  '*-~n];a=["^","/!\\","---"]
	for i in range(n):
		for r,R in zip(a,g[i*2:]):R[(i-n)%2*2+(r>"]"):]=r
	g[-2][1]="^";g[-1][1]="-";return g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU9BCsIwEDy3r4gLYhIbpZFeWuIjek2jFGxjBLch1IMe/HpM7V5mZxhmGP@e7xOeYrwNIxkpsjrPrNIaCBhejVMgV@JwR8iOiy@aplcaLlDAcdN1CYQQYPJs8bnkI6FHO6wpfzEU7SJ/nKd9YbXjsjasbjV1AtlWcrmn4QwGWG1USM1aSKNLo1JHk0i5EgFNGOZXQGKjDw5nCh3C4TE5pM/eU1j/Ig2oWLr4Aw)

-4 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder
-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Frech

Comment: `' '*2*n` can be `'  '*n` (two spaces there, but eugh... SE markdown), and then `'  '*n+'  '` can be replaced by `'  '*-~n` for [168 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY/BDoIwEETP8BV1E0OLrQYMF0h/gmuppolQa@LSNHjQg79ei@xld14mM1n/Xu4znmO8jROZKLI2z6xUCgjospnmQK7EYUFIUYov6s5IBRfgcNoNQ1pCCNB5tvpc8pFg0I5byh8G3q/44zw13CpX1q1mba@oE8j2dVkfaJAyJbJWy5Cqlai1qvSKuiSqTQjowri8AhIbfXC4UBgQjo/ZIX0aT2G7efqgYWniDw).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Oh cool, thanks!

Comment: I think `r=="^"` can be `r>"]"`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Appears to be so, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 100 bytes

```python
lambda n:n%2*'  '+' ^\n'+'\n'.join(['/!\\\n---^','  /!\\\n ^---'][i%2]for i in range(n,0,-1))+'\n -'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxLCgIxEESv0i6GTjTxk40geJLpCUQ02qKVIczG08eImype8aj5szwKQstnaa/0vlwT4YQhrJmIN0xR0KvH9lkUZuTdSkTgvY/suvNHin3gadQhTLlUUlJQTbjfDNze@YO1vxPy3OaqWCibo21f)

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 25 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
 ^¶ -”.∫2%«I"X¬ΒNN┘y7¹‘∆ž
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JTIwJTVFJUI2JTIwLSV1MjAxRC4ldTIyMkIyJTI1JUFCSSUyMlglQUMldTAzOTJOTiV1MjUxOHk3JUI5JXUyMDE4JXUyMjA2JXUwMTdF,inputs=Mw__)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 87 bytes

```c
f(n){for(puts(n%2?"   ^":" ^");n;)puts(n--%2?"  /!\\\n ^---":"/!\\\n---^");puts(" -");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3BCgIxDETv@YpYEBLWIHoRrOKPlAUpVHIwiq6nZb@9ZtvLMGHeZLI8cq61kPFcXh96/6Yv2fZ4C4g4hnNw4WiReyDSo/0mpWQ4iogz/XK/sg0MKG6X@ryrEcMM/g3VJtTYbJN1T6@HqJdT1GHgQsq7XvcyLNDRCn8)

Comment: Suggest `"   ^"-~n%2*2` instead of `n%2?"   ^":" ^"`

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 82 bytes

```python
def f(n):x=n%2;print' '*x*2,'^'+(-~n/2*"\n/!\\\n---^\n  /!\\\n ^---")[x*9:]+'\n -'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcixDkAwEADQXzkSubZcGt0QX@J0omE5IoZa/Ho1Mb53Pvd2iEtpWQMEJbqPo1RuOK9dbgQ00bgGPdaKXrHOlCy2YGYhIs8C8At8dqmnaLp@rjEHYQqq1ekD)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 42 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
É·>'^ú¶•2ÂŸ§'vôÅ•"-
 ^\!/"ÅвJ12ôIL<Rè`„ -J
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AUgAt/9vc2FiaWX//8OJwrc@J17DusK24oCiMsOCxbjCpyd2w7TDheKAoiItCiBeXCEvIsOF0LJKMTLDtElMPFLDqGDigJ4gLUr//zM) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/qquSZV1BaYqWgZO9ny6XkX1oC4en8P9x5aLudetzhXYe2PWpYZHS46eiOQ8vVyw5vOdwK5CvpcinExSjqKx1uvbDJy9Do8BY/H5ugwysSHjXMU9D1@q9zaJv9fwA).

**Minor 42 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) alternative:**

```
É·ðú„^
•e
QΣœKΔ•"- ^
\!/"ÅвJ8₂‚£ILRè»…
 -J
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AU0Asv9vc2FiaWX//8OJwrfDsMO64oCeXgrigKJlClHOo8WTS86U4oCiIi0gXgpcIS8iw4XQsko44oKC4oCawqNJTFLDqMK74oCmCiAtSv//Mw) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/qquSZV1BaYqWgZO9ny6XkX1oC4en8P9x5aPvhDYd3PWqYF8f1qGFRKlfgucVHJ3ufmwLkKOkqxHHFKOorHW69sMnL4lFT06OGWYcW@/kEHV5xaPejhmVcCrpe/3UObbP/DwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
É              # Check if the (implicit) input-integer is odd (1 if odd; 0 if even)
 ·             # Double that (2 if odd; 0 if even)
  >            # Increase it by 1 (3 if odd; 1 if even)
   '^         '# Push string "^" 
     ú         # Pad it with the input%2*2+1 amount of leading spaces
¶              # Push a newline character "\n"
•2ÂŸ§'vôÅ•    '# Push compressed integer 193455283599881836
 "-\n ^\!/"Åв  # Convert it to custom base-"-\n ^\!/"
               # (which converts it to base-length and indices it into the string)
  J            # Join this list of characters together to a single string:
               #  "  /!\\n ^---\n/!\\n---^\n"
   12ô         # Split it into parts of size 12: ["  /!\\n ^---\n","/!\\n---^\n"]
      IL       # Push a list in the range [1, input]
        <      # Decrease each by 1 to make the range [0, input)
         R     # Reverse it to range (input, 0]
          è    # Index each into the pair of strings (0-based and modulair)
           `   # Pop and push all strings separated to the stack
„ -            # Push string " -"
J              # Join all strings on the stack together
               # (and output the result implicitly)

É·             # Same as above
  ðú           # Pad a space character with that many spaces
    „^\n       # Push string "^\n"
•e\nQΣœKΔ•     # Push integer 11080812880919929
"- ^\n\!/"ÅвJ  # Same as above: "/!\\n---^  /!\\n ^---"
8₂‚            # Push 8 and 26 paired together: [8,26]
   £           # Split the string into parts of that size: ["/!\\n---^","  /!\\n ^---"]
    IL         # Push a list in the range [1, input]
      R        # Reverse it to range [input, 1]
       è       # Index each into the pair of strings (0-based and modulair)
        »      # Join this list with newline delimiter
…\n -          # Push string "\n -"
J              # Join all strings on the stack together
               # (and output the result implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•2ÂŸ§'vôÅ•` is `193455283599881836` and `•e\nQΣœKΔ•` is `11080812880919929`.
[The compressed ASCII-string was generation with this 05AB1E tip.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120966/52210)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org), <strike>97</strike> 94 bytes

```
puts "  "*(a%2)+" ^";f=->n{puts""+["/!\\\n---^","  /!\\\n ^---"][n%2];(n>1)?f[n-1]:puts(" -")}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##JYtLCoQwEAWv0j4QktFG43JEPUg@EBdZNuKMCxHPHhWXr6reus17joNp87L9fwQifFQsO12BAvo08CjHo4DKoimcc8LMAfWdvpPCDeCtlJ3vlYxGT8kKG/99fgrE0GdONvp8AQ)

I was unable to find a way to fit the entire thing in one function, so `f` is set to the lambda.

Based on [TotallyHuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman)'s Python answer.